# triggerHandler prevents change event to execute

Tags: jquery

I have radio input wrapped in div. Click on the div should trigger click on the radio input. I use triggerhandler to prevent error:maximum call stack size exceeded.

There is a change listener on radio (if radio changes trigger some action) However this fires only if I click directly on radio, it does not fire if I click on wrapper. How should I solve this? Thank you. 
https://jsfiddle.net/cewb2kpu/2/

**HTML**

```html
    <div class="inputwrapper">
      <input type="radio" name="age1" value="30"> 0 - 30
    </div>
    <div class="inputwrapper">
      <input type="radio" name="age2" value="60"> 31 - 60
    </div>
    <div class="inputwrapper">
      <input type="radio" name="age3" value="100"> 61 - 100
    </div>
```

**Jquery**

```
    $('.inputwrapper').click(function () {
          $(this).children('input').attr('checked', 'checked').triggerHandler('click');

         $(this).siblings('.inputwrapper').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });

     $('input[type=radio][name="age2"]').change(function(){
     alert('changed');
     });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted a solution here - hope I understood your problem correctly
https://jsfiddle.net/4kc571ge/2/

Try the following:

**HTML**

```html
<div class="inputwrapper">
  <input type="radio" name="age1" class="aradio"  value="30"> 0 - 30
</div>
<div class="inputwrapper">
  <input type="radio" name="age2"  class="aradio" value="60"> 31 - 60
</div>
<div class="inputwrapper">
  <input type="radio" name="age3" class="aradio" value="100"> 61 - 100
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.inputwrapper').click(function (e) {
   $('.aradio').prop('checked', false);
     $(this).children('input').prop('checked', true).triggerHandler('click');
     $(this).addClass('selected');
});

 $('.aradio').change(function(){
     alert('changed');
 });

  $('.inputwrapper').click(function(){
     alert('changed');
 });
```

Comment: I employed classes (easier than siblings)  Also used `prop` instead of `attr`.  That is just my personal preference so I coded it as such and it works.

Comment: Sorry I spoke a bit too soon. Both click and change functions are in separate files. I can not put it all together like this.

Comment: sure no problem

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
$(this).children('input').attr('checked', 'checked').triggerHandler('click');
```

To this:

```
$(this).children('input').attr('checked', 'checked').change();
```

Doing this **will execute the change event instead of click**.

```js
$('.inputwrapper').click(function () {
   $(this).children('input').attr('checked', 'checked').change();

  $(this).siblings('.inputwrapper').removeClass('selected');
 $(this).addClass('selected');
});

 $('input[type=radio][name="age2"]').change(function(){
 alert('changed');
 });
```

```css
.inputwrapper {height:20px; width:200px; background:green;margin-bottom:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="inputwrapper">
  <input type="radio" name="age1" value="30"> 0 - 30
</div>
<div class="inputwrapper">
  <input type="radio" name="age2" value="60"> 31 - 60
</div>
<div class="inputwrapper">
  <input type="radio" name="age3" value="100"> 61 - 100
</div>
```

Comment: I need to execute click event

Comment: @user1031742 In that case only change your event for name="age2" input from .change to .click

Comment: if I change it to click, it works only if I click directly on radio button. clicking inside wrapper does not trigger click.

Comment: Ok please see the latest version (so now you have both to examine)

Answer (score 0):

Ok here I think this version does not trigger the alert on div click: https://jsfiddle.net/yk1mdzwL/1/

**HTML**

```
<div class="inputwrapper">
  <input type="radio" name="age1" class="aradio"  value="30"> 0 - 30
</div>
<div class="inputwrapper">
  <input type="radio" name="age2"  class="aradio" value="60"> 31 - 60
</div>
<div class="inputwrapper">
  <input type="radio" name="age3" class="aradio" value="100"> 61 - 100
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.inputwrapper').click(function (e) {
     $('.aradio').prop('checked', false);
     $(this).children('input').prop('checked', true).triggerHandler('click');
     $(this).addClass('selected');
});

 $('.aradio').change(function(){
     alert('changed');
 });
```

Comment: please read the updated question. This does not trigger alert if you click on wrapper.

Comment: The first one that I posted *does* trigger when you click on the wrapper the second one *does not*.  Sorry what am I missing?